# KVO: Cannot remove an observer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, key-value-coding

In my interface I have an `NSTextField` who's `value` is bound to an `NSArrayController's` `selection.selectedType.title`. All of the `NSArrayController's` objects are custom objects each with two methods:

```
- (MYType *)selectedType;
- (void)setSelectedType: (MYType *)type;
```

The **don't** have an iVar `selectedType`. However, they do have an iVar holding all `MYType` objects. The code boils down to this:

```
- (MYType *)selectedType
{
   if (someIndex == 0)
        return [types objectAtIndex: 0];
    else
        return [self typeWithIndex: someIndex];
}

- (void)setSelectedType: (MYType *)type
{
     someIndex = [type index];  
}
```

`MYType` objects got a `NSString *title` iVar with a corresponding `@property` and `synthesize`.

Whenever I call `setSelectedType:`, the changes are immediately visible in the `NSTextField` and everything seems to work but I get a log message saying:

> Cannot remove an observer NSArrayController 0x141160 for the key
>   path "selectedType.title" from MYType 0x1a4830, most
>   likely because the value for the key "selectedType" has
>   changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the
>   KVO-compliance of the MYType class.

I tried encapsulating the `setSelectedType:` method with `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` and then I still got a log message but a different one:

> Cannot remove an observer NSKeyValueObservance 0x1c7570 for the key
>   path "title" from MYType 0x1a4be0 because it is not registered as an
>   observer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use accessors. Don't access your ivars directly. You're bypassing the KVO for `someIndex` because you modify the ivar directly. Don't touch ivars directly unless you have to.

You also need to let KVO know that `selectedType` depends on `someIndex` (and/or `someStuff`; it's not clear from your distilled code).

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSelectedType
{
  return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"someIndex", nil];
}
```

This tells the KVO system that whenever `someIndex` changes, it causes an implicit change in `selectedType`. See [Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-SW3).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error but for a different reason. Probably worth mentioning it in case anyone else winds up here.

I'm writing an app in Swift and I'd forgotten to prefix the var with `dynamic`